# How do I pass a non static method as an argument in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What I want to do is easiest to understand from a code example:

```
class A {
    List<B> bs;

    void batchFuntion(List<B> selectedBs, MethodOfB){
        for (B b in selectedBs) {
        b.MethodOfB();
        }
    }
}

class B {
    void foo() {
        do something;
    }
}

// so to apply any method of B to a selection of B items in A:
a_instance.batchFuntion(selectedBs, foo);
```

In other words:
I have two classes, A and B. A holds a list of B items. I want to batch-wise apply methods of B on selected B items in a given instance of A. Because there are many different methods that I want to do this for, I don't want to write a new A-method for every B-method. But I don't know how to pass a non-static method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you need `selectedBs` here since you're not using this parameter in `batchFunction`, but regarding `MethodOfB` you can pass a function parameter. Something like that:

```dart
class A {
  List<B> bs;

  void batchFuntion(List<B> selectedBs, void Function(B b) apply) {
    for (B b in bs) {
      apply(b);
    }
  }
}

class B {
  void foo() {}
}

a_instance.batchFuntion(selectedBs, (b) => b.foo());
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I needed. selectedBs was missing in the batch function, I edited the question.